# Bing Spell Checker is not working as expected

Tags: spell-checking, bing-api

https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/spellcheck?text=mus&mkt=en-GB&mode=spell

Using the above URL and given my supplied API key within the request headers - I am getting no results back from the Bing Spell Checker API using PostMan or from Refit in C#(Xamarin Forms).

For 'mus' I'm expecting 'must', for 'tst' I'm expecting 'test' but, neither seem to work.

I've set the mode to 'spell' which should be the case however, even in 'proof' mode it doesn't return any results.

Please can somebody let me know why?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide more information on what exactly is returned by bing-API! Is there any response text, JSON, HTTP status code or other network traffic you can share with us?

Comment: The response JSON just indicates no matches for both 'mst' and 'tst' attempts.

Comment: Did you try phrases like `mst have` and `quality tst`? Do they return no matches, too?

Comment: Did you try a normal search? Does this return anything?

Comment: @Markus yes 'quality tst' returned 'test' and 'mst have' returned 'must'. While you have answered my question it's not really ideal that the Bing Spell Checker API doesn't return the desired results given the queries. I'm about to give up on this but, I will mark your response as the best answer. Please answer so that I can do so!

Comment: tst stans for Thiosulfate sulfurtransferase and hence passes. There are many such unfortunate acronyms that will not be corrected without added context. The only API that I know of and can correct this is OpenAI using the davinci or curie model, You can instruct it to spellcheck as a command. It gets tst straight away, but changes mst into mist unless you have "I mst". It works better because it takes into account frequent mistypes by real users. I am using it for exactly this purpose. The downside is that it is considerably slower, but this can be mitigated within code, e.g. multiprocessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/search-apis/bing-spell-check/overview) explains:

> Bing Spell Check API lets you perform contextual grammar and spell checking on a text string. While most spell-checkers rely on dictionary-based rule sets, the Bing spell-checker leverages machine learning and statistical machine translation to provide accurate and contextual corrections.

I assume that passing single words in most cases won’t provide enough information for this approach.

Try passing phrases that put your words in some reasonable context like `mst have` or `quality tst`.

For single word suggestions you can try a dictionary based service or software package.